# Context path not working in liferay Hook

Tags: hook, liferay-6

I am creating a hook in which i want to add my image in custom jsp.

I have added image inside **docroot/images/1.jpg**

in jsp i am trying to access it using

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/1.jpg"  />
```

but i am not able to get image.

Additionally when i am trying to print <%=request.getContextPath()%> is only prints **"/"**

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking images from your war (docroot folder), suggest you to place the images in a Web server so that in future you can easily replace them if you want to change images.

You could use below code in your jsp page to retrieve from Web server,

```
<div class="yourCSSClass">
        <liferay-ui:icon src="/yourWebServerPath/1.jpg" label="" message=""/>
</div>
```

Another flavour of it,

In your JSP page if you have below code,

```
<nav class="yourCSSClass"><br/><br/></nav>
```

Then, in the CSS file that you are importing in your JSP page, use this,

```
.yourCSSClass{
    background: url(yourWebServerPath/1.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
```

**P.S** : In both the above examples, decide properly the value for `yourWebServerPath`

Comment: This is not a good solution to a very specific problem of the user asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but still worth answering.

Your **hook** replaces portal’s JSPs with your owns but that doesn’t mean that *the context* of the new JSPs is your hook’s one.

What actually happens is that JSPs are replaced at the File System level, and called by other Liferay JSPs and configuration as they were the original one.

The `request` you have access to, therefore, is the main and original one.

As far as I know, there’s no clean way to get the context path of the hook that is providing an overriding JSPs.